# Doctrine - DQL select query error with FKs even with IDENTITY

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a DQL query that should to return a FK. But, even with IDENTITY, I got a query error.

My entities fields:

```
//Profile.php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Gabrieljmj\ProfileBundle\Entity\Website\Website", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
private $websites;

//Website.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Gabrieljmj\ProfileBundle\Entity\Profile", inversedBy="websites")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="p_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $profile;
```

My DQL:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(p.websites)
FROM   ProfileBundle:Profile AS p
WHERE  p.u_id = :u_id
```

And the error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'websites)
>   ': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.

I can't give more details cause it's all that I know. I searched for similar problems, but all of them are not using IDENTITY yet (that's their problem).

Answer (score 0):

Try a join. Something like this

```
SELECT p, w FROM ProfileBundle:Profile p JOIN p.websites w
```

Comment: There's no way to get just the websites? I don't want unnecessary information